# Custom Groups in Google Data Studio

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio

In Google Analytics I have a custom dimension C-Age capturing age (since Google themselves are not able to automatically capture this on every visitor). In data studio I would like to aggregate this now in age groups: `18-24 / 25-34 / 35-44/ 45-54 / 55-65 / 65+`

However, I seem to be unable to count instances of a metric by dimension. I have the metric users on my custom dimension C_Age.

I have tried this with CASE / WHEN but haven't been able to get the formula working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

1. Set the aggregation method for `C-Age` to `None` in the Fields screen.
2. Create a calculated field using CASE / WHEN to set the proper bins for age groups.
3. If you want to count instances, you can just add another calculated field `Visitor Count` with the formula `1+0` or do a unique count on any unique identifier you might have.

This should solve your issue.